# Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

I am new to Spring and creating login page using Spring mvc, I cannot connect database(mysql) to the application.

I had the latest version of hibernate 5.
 the exception is:

Type Exception Report  Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection  Descr

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.vikram"></context:component-scan>

<!-- database connection pooling  -->
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webapplication?useSSL=false" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="vikram#123" />

    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.telusko.tusk.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" /> 

</beans>


enter code here
package com.vikram.webapp;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.vikram.dao.Logindao;
import com.vikram.entity.Loginentity;

@Controller
public class IndexController 

{
    @Autowired
    Logindao logindao;

    Loginentity loginet;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        return "index.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login.htm")
    public String login()
    {
        System.out.println("I am at login");
        return "login.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/checklogin")
    public String collectingloginvalues(@ModelAttribute ("loginet") Loginentity loginet)
    {
        System.out.println("I am at checkinlogin");
        logindao.checklogin(loginet);
        return "index.jsp";
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add little more context by providing the code that you're trying to run with the actual error trace?

Comment: Can u add the full error stack trace, So that it will be helpful to view and answer?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided the full stack trace, I could suggest you the below solution.
If this has occurred because of connection pool problem , then please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42900541/10726103)! for the answer. 
Try this out it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly .. for this problem you couldn't open connection  with mysql .. you should two Check that you databases is open ... and  you should check that your properties  is correct .. if yes The problem is the compatibility of older versions of MySQL Connector/J with MySQL 8. You need to upgrade to or - better - 8.0.11 (or a higher version).

Comment: can you provide more context to your answer? why he have to change the connector version ?